# Convertion OpenApi 3.0 yaml / json into word document

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I would like to convert openAPI yaml / json file into word document. Is there any way how to do it? I found only **json** to **pdf** solutions which look not very nice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.